# Exclude certain children when selecting a div with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jQuery and trying to select all items within a div except some specific ones, but I can't find any way to do it. When using my website, the user can scroll by dragging the mouse but I want some elements inside the `containerTable` to be excluded from this. I would like to select all items within `#containerTable` and `.year` but not the ones with class `.window`.

I tried the filter function, but it didn't work, I selected none of the items.

```
$('#containerTable, .year').filter('.window').on({
            'mousemove': function(e) {
                clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
                //etc.....
            });
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) at this context,

```
$('#containerTable *, .year *').not('.window')
```

`not` will exclude the element matching with the passed selector. But `filter` will filter out the particular element matches with the selector.

As per your new requirement in the comment, you should use event delegation.

```
$('#containerTable, .year').on("mousemove", '#containerTable *:not(.window), .year *:not(.window)', function(e) {
  clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
  //etc.....
});
```

where `#containerTable` and `.year` should be static. That means it has to be available when binding event.

Comment: Afraid it didn't work... Could the problem maybe be that I load this function before any elements with class .window have been created?

Comment: @e.klara.k You can use event delegation to tackle that issue.